# How to extract numbers from json string in apex

Tags: apex, integration, json, salesforce-id

**JSON Body**

```js
{
  "60":{"name":"test_Z","provider":"21","status":"enabled"},
  "61":{"name":"test_S","provider_id":"21","status":"enabled"},
  "62":{"name":"test_G","provider":"21","status":"enabled"}
}
```

**Result Expected:**
I need to get result like test_Z = 60 and test_S = 61 , and test_G =62
this number will change based on API calls

Comment: You can run the code 'Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);' and loop thru the map collection to get the required values.

Comment: I have added the map like this

Comment: I have added the code like this

Comment: getting error name does not exist 
Map<String, object> m = (Map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

                    set<string> strSet = m.keySet();
                    for(string idvals : m){
                          string  maintid ;
                            maintid =m.get(idvals).Name; // getting error here 
                          if(maintid.contains('Test_MT_Z') != null)
                              maintid = idvals;

Comment: Inside the for loop, you can access the name property value as '((Map<String, Object>)m.get(idvals)).get('name')'. However, I would like to point out that this way of JSON parsing can be used for simple JSON content. Better to use the solution pointed out by @Sander de Jong.